# Set how often localStorage is saving

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am creating a online text editor.

I have using jQuery to store the information on the client side

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#type-name').blur(saveSettings);
    loadSettings();
});

function loadSettings() {
    $('#type-name').val(localStorage.typewriter);
}

function saveSettings() {
    localStorage.typewriter = $('#type-name').val();
}
```

This will save what the user has wrote but not everything. It seems to only save a certain amount and reverting back to what was there before. But when I leave it for 20 seconds it saves and works. What can I do to change the save rate?

Comment: Your browser fires `blur` events on inputs if you leave them alone for 20s? That's strange. Why don't you hook on `keyup`?

Comment: You could also use `setInterval()`.

Comment: It sounds like OP is saying that using 'blur' is causing some kind of localStorage rate-limit to be reached.

Comment: using .keyup seems to have solved the issue. Looks like blur is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var blur_timeout_id;

    $('#type-name').blur(function () {
        if (blur_timeout_id) {
            clearTimeout(blur_timeout_id);
        }

        blur_timeout_id = setTimeout(function () {
            saveSettings();
        }, 1000); // or 10000, etc.
    });

    loadSettings();
});

function loadSettings() {
    $('#type-name').val(localStorage.typewriter);
}

function saveSettings() {
    localStorage.typewriter = $('#type-name').val();
}
```